# VSCode extension development with webviews using Svelte hangs the process

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

I was working on a VSCode extension that had a side-bar webview powered by Svelte, and the script was loading but never running, just hanging itself and ending the process before any of the code was able to be executed. This would then cause the webview to crash, causing VSCode to crash.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

function getNonce() {
    let text = '';
    const possible =
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}

export class SideBarProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
    _view?: vscode.WebviewView;
    _doc?: vscode.TextDocument;

    constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {}

    public resolveWebviewView(webviewView: vscode.WebviewView) {
        this._view = webviewView;

        webviewView.webview.options = {
            localResourceRoots: [this._extensionUri],
        };

        webviewView.webview.html = this._getHtmlForWebview(webviewView.webview);

        webviewView.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(async (data) => {
            console.log(data)
        });
    }

    public revive(panel: vscode.WebviewView) {
        this._view = panel;
    }

    private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview) {
        const styleResetUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
            vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'styles', 'reset.css')
        );
        const styleVSCodeUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
            vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'styles', 'vscode.css')
        );

        const scriptUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
            vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'out', 'compiled/SideBar.js')
        );
        const styleMainUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
            vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, 'out', 'compiled/out/compiledSideBar.css')
        );
        const getOptions = (): vscode.WebviewOptions => {
            return { 
                enableScripts: true,
            }
        }

        webview.options = getOptions()

        const nonce = getNonce();
        return `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!--
            Use a content security policy to only allow loading images from https or from our extension directory,
            and only allow scripts that have a specific nonce.
-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src https: data:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' ${webview.cspSource}; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}'; allow-scripts: 'self'">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="${styleResetUri}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${styleVSCodeUri}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="${styleMainUri}" rel="stylesheet">
<script nonce="${nonce}">
  const tsvscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
</script>
    </head>
<body>
        <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>`;
    }
}
```

This code provides the web-view to VSCode and renders it, and this is the Svelte code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
</script>
<button id="refresh">Refresh tasks</button>
<style>
</style>
```

Comment: your extension is not the root of the workspace

Comment: I am aware.. Is this a problem?

Comment: https://salvage.is-inside.me/ODXSbTGo.png it creates the icon - just hangs tho

Comment: @rioV8 have you got discord so we can chat better?

Comment: No Discord xxxx

Comment: ok, then do you know a soloution to this issue? maybe you can try to develop locally?

Comment: Oh and, @rioV8 I'm using rollup to bundle. I don't think this changes anything..

Comment: I seriously don't mean to bother by @rioV8 is there anyway you could help me get this fixed now? I kinda need it done soon